# Mutually exclusive and not mutually exclusive

Tags: grammar

I have found on website that when an event is **mutually exclusive** it means occurrence of one preclude of the other. So is it grammatically correct to write *not mutually exclusive* when it is already negative?

Comment: Your question is unclear. But yes, "*not mutually exclusive*" is correct English and meaningful. It means that the two or more things concerned are not mutually exclusive: they can overlap.

Comment: What I want to say is that writing not mutually exclusive is grammatically correct or not

Comment: The events 'the card I've just drawn is a diamond' and 'the card I've just drawn is black' are mutually exclusive. But the events 'the card I've just drawn is a diamond' and 'the card I've just drawn is a three' are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Drew says in his comment:

> "not mutually exclusive" is correct English and meaningful. It means that the two or more things concerned are not mutually exclusive: they can overlap.

However, I suspect you misunderstand the caution against "double negatives".  This caution revolves around words that are or contain variations of "no" and "not".  For example:

> I did**n't** go **no**where.
>
> They did**n't** **n**ever agree.

The problem is that, in certain English dialects, the duplication of "no"/"not" is used as an intensifier, despite the logic of the sentence being the opposite of what is intended.

When you use "no"/"not" with a different word that happens to have a negative meaning, it is universally clear what you mean.

Comment: Thank you very much wfaulk, yes i understand clearly