# "Jenny didn't never want to go home"

Tags: grammaticality

There is a dialog in the movie Forrest Gump which said

> For some reason Jenny didn't never want to go home.

I wonder if this sentence is correct or not. I think it shoud be:

> For some reason Jenny didn't ever want to go home.

Which one is right?

Comment: The answer [to another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216773/mutually-exclusive-and-not-mutually-exclusive/216778#216778) probably answers this.

Comment: Technically, it should be the second version of the sentence; idiomatically, in casual conversation, the first version can be used—and, in that context,  it has the same meaning as the second version.

Comment: Also, the double-negative is often used in literature and other creative works as a marker to indicate that the person who says it is not well-educated, or comes from a poor background.